# Overlapping Type Class Instances in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typeclass, type-safety

I'm writing a geometry library in Haskell that makes good use of type classes and the type checker to help enforce the validity of geometric operations. However the compiler complains that I have overlapping instances. Below is a minimal example, where I have replaced vector types with `Int` to simplify the code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class PointSet a where
  liesIn :: Int -> a -> Bool

data Line = Line Int Int

class TopVec a where
  linearSpan :: a -> Line

instance PointSet Line where
  point `liesIn` _ = True

class BoundLinear a where
  direction  :: a -> Int

instance (BoundLinear bdl) => TopVec bdl where
  linearSpan bdline = Line 0 0

instance (BoundLinear bdl) => PointSet bdl where
  point `liesIn` bdline = point `liesIn` (linearSpan bdline)
```

The compiler (GHC 6.10.3) complains that I have overlapping instances for `PointSet Line`, arising from the use of `liesIn`. The matching instances are `PointSet Line` and `(BoundLinear bdl) => PointSet bdl`. But this doesn't make sense, because the the only instances of `PointSet` should be `Line` and any instance of `BoundLinear`. There should be no conflict because `Line` is not an instance of `BoundLinear`. Can anybody throw some light on this?

Comment: "There should be no conflict because Line is not an instance of BoundLinear". This is untrue, because classes are open and someone can come along and make Line and instance of BoundedLinear. More technically, there is a conflict because `bdl` (a free type variable) can be instantiated to `Line`. Even more technically, ghc only looks at the head of the instance (the part to the right of the `=>`) when deciding if instances are overlapping. You can enabled `OverlappingInstances` to make your code pass the typechecker.

Comment: But you probably shouldn't because `OverlappingInstances` is way too complicated/messy/fragile.

Comment: There are some interesting tricks with type families I've seen around here; I'm not sure if one of them would apply here.

Comment: You could have a `newtype BL a = BL{ unBL :: a}` wrapper and write the `TopVec` and `PointSet` instances for those, e.g. `instance (BoundLinear bdl) => TopVec (BL bdl) where linearSpan (BL bdline) = Line 0 0`. Then you can opt-in to use the `BoundLinear`-based instances by wrapping your type in `BL`.

Comment: @Cactus, that would work, but it would also undermine the overloading that is the whole point of working with type classes and type families.

Comment: Is there some way to tell the compiler that a certain type will never be made an instance of another class?

Comment: In this case, I'd use `liesInLine` in the last instance definition. So we can help compiler to pick the right method, unambiguously.

Comment: If more precisely you want to define `TopVec` and `PointSet` as superclasses of `BoundLinear` which instances could be automatically build upon subclass instance. 

This is [already proposed here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/IntrinsicSuperclasses) so you could wait couple years for new GHC version or wrap it to the `newtype`

Comment: FYI, I found the funky type family question I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641559/closed-type-families-and-strange-function-types. I don't think it applies directly, but you might be able to find a way to use some of those ideas.